# How to convert raw score to standardized score "sensibly"?

Tags: algorithm, statistics

I want to convert about 7,000 raw scores (0 to 20,000) to a standardized score (0 to 100).
The distribution of the scores is not normal. The median is 270 but the top dozen scores are:
18586,
17151,
9690,
8034,
7723,
7026,
7027,
6725,
6722,
5637,
4996,
4452.

How do I do this conversion in a "sensible" way such that the standardized scores (from 0 to 100) both reflect the raw scores AND the fact that half of the scores are below 270?

I don't have a definition of "sensible" and want to have your suggestions as to what is sensible in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest doing a histogram.  It is basically bin numbers together to get the frequency.  Here is the link to the Wiki http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Histogram.  If you google histogram, there are links to several other site which may be helpful.

Given the range of the data, you may want to take to log of each number and used that for the historgram.  That may help decrease the range and then scale that between 0 and 100.